# Assembly - text to number

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

I am trying to convert texto to number. Exemple I digit "321" and I need to conver it to number: 321.

First i copy to text

```
f:  mov al,es:[bx]
    mov texto[di],al        
    inc bx
    inc bx
    inc di
loop f
```

Then I want to convert to number.

```
xor di, di
mov cl, 10

li:
mov al,texto[di]
mov numero[di],al
sub al, 48
mul cl
xor al, al
inc di
loop li
```

The first code I think is ok, but the second is wrong. I don't get it.

Comment: Tips: you're using CX (well, CL) for LOOP. Why 10? String is 3 characters, you'll read garbage. First digit should be multiplied by 100, second 10, third 1. Here you multiply by...10, 9, 8, 7. Finally: why do you reset AL each time? Question: I didn't get why INC BX twice. Oh, final note: if you're trying to do this for study...ok, if it's an attempt to optimize a high used routine then I'd avoid LOOP (replace with DEC CX and JNZ).

Comment: you're doing an awful amount of moving data around, and relatively little actual work on that data. You may want to eliminate some of that moving data, as it serves no real practical purpose, other than having data somewhere else than it was before

Comment: also, multiplying two factors and obtainung a product is no doubt very satisfactory - but what happens to the poor result if you don't deal with it, like, putting it somewhere, rather than simply ignoring it - which is just as good as never having multiplied at all.

Answer (score 2):

It can help to code in a HHL before assembly.  If the algorithm is at all complex, run it in the HLL so that you're sure it works before committing to assembly code.  For example, this:

```
char text[] = "321";
int n_chars = 3;
int val = 0;
int i = 0;

next:
  val = 10 * val + text[i++] - '0';
  if (--n_chars) goto next;
```

In MASM,

```
mov bl, 10 ; constant multiplier
mov cl, 3  ; n_chars = 3
xor ax, ax ; val = 0
xor si, si ; i = 0 

next:
  mul bl           ; val = 10 * val
  add ax, text[si] ; val = val + text[i]
  sub ax, '0'      ; val = val - '0'
  inc si           ; i++
  loop next        ; if (--nChars) goto next
```

Answer (score 1):

you just want to convert "321" to 321?

You have to sub 30h to each value and add it to the final number.
example:

```
.8086
.model small
.stack 2048

DATA segment para public 'data' 
number db '321$' 
final dw 0
DATA ends

CODE segment para public 'code'
    assume CS:CODE, DS:DATA

main proc 
mov ax, DATA 
mov ds, ax 



    mov si,0
    mov cx,10
    xor bx,bx 

    cicle:
        mov ax,final
        mul cx

        mov final,ax

        mov bl,number[si]
        sub bl,30h

        add final,bx

        inc si 

        cmp number[si],'$'
        jne cicle

        MOV AH,4ch
        INT 21h
        MAIN endp 

        CODE ends
        END MAIN
```

I know it is not fully functional and you should expect some bugs.

EDIT:
I just wanted to give an example so he could understand.
Here is a full functional code. As long as the digit are before '$' it will work perfectly.

Comment: [bl] can not be used as an address register, but [bx] and [ebx].